# Is it acceptable to use an answerbox as a comment if you need the extended space?

Tags: discussion

I used an answer in [Grand Sum with distinct in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310814/grand-sum-with-distinct-in-sql-server) basically as a comment. I did so because the comment would be much clearer with a table in it, which is impossible in a comment. Someone told me there I shouldn't do that. So,

- Is it? If so, why?
- How should I deal with comments that are more clearly expressed with additional markup that isn't available in the comment box?

Comment: Re down votes: This question is asking if doing `X` is a good thing or not. Down voting because you think `X` is a bad thing isn't wildly helpful (vote on the actual linked answer if you *must*, although I think it's unhelpful to vote based on things the OP themseleves brought up to ask if they were ok), this question itself seems fair, and the second half doesn’t seem like a duplicate (not that duplicates should necessarily be down voted anyway).

Comment: Good question IMO

Comment: @RichardTingle I guess that downvotes here are (at least in part) caused by an expectation that near 2k user should already know the difference between answer and comment.

Comment: @Mołot there is a difference between not knowing the difference, and ignoring it because it seemed more useful in this case :)

Comment: @Martijn all 1rep users who post comments as an answers because they cannot comment thinks it is more useful in their cases ;p People who ask for recommendations usually thinks that in their specific case it is useful, too. And so on. Certainly we don't want them to feel justified ;)

Comment: @Mołot apparently I have a lot to learn :) Why is it good to downvote a question on meta if the SO user is supposed to 'know better'? Or should that rather be a question for meta-meta?

Comment: @Martijn I think you need to go at least 4 levels deep before you'll be able to ask that and make us believe its our own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## In the general case

The key goal of Stack Exchange is to remove noise. It is essential that the question and answer are very clear and not "mixed in" with anything else. Even the existing comments are considered a "necessary evil" and are hidden away as much as possible.

This is a key difference between forums and the Q&A model and so is particularly well defended

**As such the answer box is for answers only, no exceptions.**

Currently there is no way to use extended markup within comments, this is by design as comments are supposed to be used to ask for clarification rather that to actually post content. Admittedly sometime part answers are posted as comments. This isn't really what they're there for (although I have done it myself) but in this case requiring full markup is a good sign that it should be a real answer

## In your specific case

Your comment seems to have been "What should happen if the city names are the same but the collection values are different", which doesn't really require the table.

Comment: Sometimes users do offer hints or suggestions in comments when they aren't sure if the suggestion would actually be helpful, however that is not the intent of the comments.

Comment: require is a strong word; I do think it improves clarity, which seems needed, as the question is at a fairly basic level, and some visual aid is helpful. That said, I don't want to go against consensus. Although I'm still not positive on how to help the OP, is it the best idea to delete the answer?

Comment: @Martijn I'm sure it will have picked up quite a few flags already. I'd delete it yourself before someone else does

Comment: @Martijn If we have comments as answers we will end up with the forum horror that stack exchange was designed to avoid

Comment: @RichardTingle sorry to engulf you with questions, but why should I do it before someone else does (rather than just do it because it's considered unhelpful)?

Comment: @RichardTingle shouldn't the down/upvotes automatically bubble this down, and other answers that are not meant as comments up, avoiding the forum horror?

Comment: @Martijn I suppose just to be helpful really (and you keep control of its deleted/non deleted state if you feel like upgrading it to an answer in the future). Nothing bad is going to happen if a moderator deletes it (unless this happens over and over again)

Comment: @Martijn True, although (a) that gives you a load of downvotes and (b) that mixes up new answers and new comments. Also with the other orderings: activity and newest, they remain mixed in

Comment: @Martijn but it also creates the appearance that such "non-answer" answers are acceptable.  1 downvoted comment answer on 1 question is not a problem.  Dozens on multiple posts start to become an issue.

Comment: is it acceptable/reasonable/desirable to keep them around for discussion for as long as the discussion is somewhat fruitful, and delete them after? Would that "fix" the problem posed by psubsee and Richards B, or is it just not productive? Richard about A, I don't particularly see how a is a negative, that seems to be working as intended. How is that a problem?

Comment: @Martijn Its a bad thing for *you* to be getting lots of downvotes. It reduces your reputation and in extreme cases can lead to an answer ban (I'm sure very unlikely in your case, but still)

Comment: I think I can live with that :)